# FOSUserBundle 2.0 with symfony 3.4.4 : Unrecognized field: usernameCanonical

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I've just set up the FOSUserBundle according to the documentation and all fields have been created in the database (see below).

Now when I want to register the first User I receive this error message:

Unrecognized field: usernameCanonical

What am I doing wrong?

here's my setup (php 7.2.1 on Windows 7):

> php bin/console doctrine:mapping:info

```
Found .. mapped entries:
...
[OK]  App\Entity\User
...
[OK]  FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group
[OK]  FOS\UserBundle\Model\User
```

> php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate

```
[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.
```

User.php:

```
<php
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FeeRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=true, hardDelete=true)
 */
class User extends BaseUser {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * 
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * 
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * 
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $modified;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * 
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $deletedAt;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

//    getters and setters for created, modified and deletedAt

}
```

fos_user.yaml:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: App\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: user@example.com
        sender_name: "Sender Name"
    service:
        mailer: 'fos_user.mailer.noop'
```

doctrine.yaml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
    ...
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App

            FOSUserBundle: ~
```

Database-Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `fos_user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(180) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `username_canonical` varchar(180) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(180) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email_canonical` varchar(180) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `confirmation_token` varchar(180) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `password_requested_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `roles` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)',
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Appreciate any hints where to look, and what to try

Thanks!

Comment: what's the **repositoryClass="App\Repository\FeeRepository"** in your User Entity Class?!

Comment: and what does the **FOSUserBundle: ~** in your orm mappings section? for us it's working without mappings - but could be different for your app.

Comment: Argh, silly me, been looking everywhere but there :(

Thanks for the heads up - that's been the problem!

Comment: seen that FOSUserBundle: ~ somewhere and thought it might be needed - will remove it...